# Selenium Firefox loads the profile but the web driver part isn't working anymore

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

```
        FirefoxOptions options3 = new FirefoxOptions();
        options3.setHeadless(false);
        options3.addArguments("profile","C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\i8k6kx4s.default");
        WebDriver driver3 = new FirefoxDriver(options3);false);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver3.get("https://ramdonwebsit.com");
```

It opens the profile but does not go to the website. I am trying to load a specific profile that has saved cache data and passwords in it, so I can just go to the website straight and avoid a login issue that has captchas.

Comment: What are you doing here `WebDriver driver3 = new FirefoxDriver(options3);false);`. It should be `WebDriver driver3 = new FirefoxDriver(options3);`

Answer (score 0):

Try below -

```
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("Your_Profile");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);
Thread.sleep(1000);
driver.get("https://ramdonwebsit.com");
```